# Makefile : executing a multiline function not working

Tags: linux, makefile, centos, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with few regular targets. The makefile should download another makefile.include and include it before exec targets. I tried to do it like below. But its not working.

```
define get_file =
@echo "test echo" ;\
if [ -a ./Makefile.include ] ; \
then  \
    echo "Makefile.include present" ; \
else \
    curl -o Makefile.include https://www.blah.com/myfile ;\
fi;
endef

D := $(value get_file)

include Makefile.include
```

I tried to exec the get_file function various different ways, it just doesn't work. The only way I could get it working is by putting the function in another foo.sh and doing the following.

```
D := $(shell bash -x foo.sh)
```

but I would prefer to keep the script in the same file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean? What does it do? How does it fail?

Comment: @Beta it just doesn't echo

Comment: What version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: Nothing in this makefile actually _uses_ the `$(D)` variable so we can't tell you why it doesn't work.  All this makefile is doing is setting a variable to contain a shell script (it doesn't _run_ the shell script).  You have to show us where you use `$(D)` for us to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @MadScientist in Makefile, what you keep on the right side of ':=' is evaluated immediately. And for me I just wanted to make sure the script is executed. If there is another way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: may I know what's wrong in this question ? why is this downvoted ??

Comment: Yes, it's evaluated immediately... _AS A Makefile VALUE_.  Evaluating a makefile value does not run a shell command.  The assignment above doesn't run any recipe or shell command: it sets the variable `D` to the literal string `@echo "test echo"; if [ -a ./Makefile.include ] ; then echo "Makefile.include present" ; else curl -o Makefile.include https://www.blah.com/myfile ; fi;`  That's all it does.

Comment: @MadScientist if that is the case, can you enlighten me why "D := $(shell bash -x foo.sh)" logic is working fine. The only difference here is, the code is coming from an external file as opposed to a local function.

Comment: No, the difference is that in the latter case you're running the `$(shell ...)` make function, which explicitly invokes a shell, runs the command you give it, and sets the variable to the output of the command.  In the example in the question you're not using the `$(shell ...)` function, so the shell is not invoked.  It's the same way using `FOO := bar` doesn't run `bar` in the shell: it just sets the variable `FOO` to the value `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few little issues:

```
define get_file
echo "the parameter is: $1 - this could be the filename passed in"
if [ -a ./Makefile.include ] ; then \
    echo "Makefile.include present"; \
else \
    curl -o Makefile.include https://www.blah.com/myfile; \
fi
endef
```

Where multiline defines do not always need a `\` at the end, only the individual multiline commands within need then (like the if statement). Also I think you need to use `call` and not `value` make command - so for example use like (I added the example where you can pass in a parameter - which you may not want/need):

```
var := $(call get_file,some_parameter)

some_rule:
    @echo $(var)
```

Comment: I tried with call, eval also. no luck. I just tried with the modification you suggested. could you try this if possible and see if its working for you?

Comment: it did work for me - that is where I took the example from : ) - can you try to strip it down to just a simple echo and see (e.g. just the first line of the define)?